# Repair a vinyl pool liner

Tags: pool

Any tips on patching two small holes on an in-ground Pool liner. It’s two penny-sized holes and they’re right above the water line. I have some leftover original liner so I was hoping to try and match it.[image]

Comment: The standard vinyl glue works well with patches ;even under water.

Answer (score 3):

To tell the truth, don’t try to match pattern over getting a good seal. In my teen years we installed many in-ground concrete bottom pools with liners to avoid taxes. I haven’t tried to patch one in over 15 years so the adhesives may be much better, but my best advice from the past is make sure the seal is good no matter what. A new liner is much more expensive than a difference in the pattern.

We used to order extra liner for patches yours could be like this. Get a pro to do it with the best glue. This is the best advice I could give having patched a few and getting chem burns trying to get it exact.

Comment: "...in-ground “concrete” bottom pools with liners to avoid taxes..."  -- how's that work, Ed?

Comment: Very similar to full concrete bottom pools normally a steel side wall Munson? Was one of the best because we could order custom bottoms like 8’ at one end 4’ at the other 36’ oval was quite popular. In Northern California. There were full concrete lined pools but we only did a few of these as they did not save much on the install cost only the tax savings because of the liner they were considered temporary.